# How to make file uploading optional using Mvc 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I am uploading 3 types of files, i.e 1)video 2)image 3)document.
if i am uploading all three files at once so it is upload and show successfully, but if i want to skip one the file of uploading then it giving me following errors. Please Help me here:
 httpPostedFile.SaveAs(fileSavePath);
db.SaveChanges();
one the errors is because of sending path to db i guess.

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AddSKU(SKU_Det skufiles, IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files)
    {
        var httpPostedFile = Request.Files[0];
        if (httpPostedFile != null)
        {
            var uploadFilesDir = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Content/Videos");
            if (!Directory.Exists(uploadFilesDir))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(uploadFilesDir);          
            }

            var fileSavePath = Path.Combine(uploadFilesDir, httpPostedFile.FileName);
            httpPostedFile.SaveAs(fileSavePath);
        }
            foreach (var file in files)
            {
                if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
                {
                    file.SaveAs(HttpContext.Server.MapPath("~/Areas/Admin/Images/") + file.FileName);
                }
            }

            SKU_Det sku = new SKU_Det();

            sku.SKU = skufiles.SKU;
            sku.VideoPath = Request.Files[0].FileName;
            sku.Imagepath = sku.FilePath = Request.Files[1].FileName;
            sku.FilePath = sku.FilePath = Request.Files[2].FileName;
            db.SKU_Det.Add(sku);
            db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: httpPostedFile.SaveAs(fileSavePath); db.SaveChanges();

Comment: That isn't an error.  Please can you add the error to the question :)

Comment: Actually when i submit it empty then it gives me this error...   httpPostedFile.SaveAs(fileSavePath);

Comment: Is there an error message or exception that is being thrown?  You're just providing bits of the code.  I can say that this code is causing an error `var myInt = Int32.Parse("hello");` but I haven't posted the error, this is just the code.  It sounds to me that you're receiving unexpected behaviour from your code, not an error.  What is the unexpected behaviour?  What should the code be doing that it is not doing.

Comment: Line 50:                 httpPostedFile.SaveAs(fileSavePath);                                       is possible that i can skip one of the file upload means leave it blank?  it is not work, but if i select all three file then it work. is it any magic?

Comment: The first part of your code is selecting just the first file from the request `var httpPostedFile = Request.Files[0];` then the second part of your code loops through all files `foreach (var file in files)`.

Comment: yes you are Right Luke, in first part i am upload a video file and if skip it the the error message httpPostedFile.SaveAs(fileSavePath); is appear and when i skip image or document file then db.SaveChanges(); appear... is there any way to if i want skip video file and upload other two files is it possible?